# Can I paint and sculpt with the same stroke?

Tags: texture-painting, sculpting

[image: dynamic paint]

Dynamic paint is very close to what I want.

[image: painting w/ a texture]

"Impasto painting" this is my goal.

Maybe there is an addon?

Comment: What is a bounty? Is it like a pot of cash to anyone who can pull it off?

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/bounty

Comment: Is [this](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?376974-Addon-Import-Corel-Painter-RIFF-files-%96-for-Impasto-Depth-(3D)-Texture) the type of addon you are looking for? http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?376974-Addon-Import-Corel-Painter-RIFF-files-%96-for-Impasto-Depth-(3D)-Texture it claims to be able to extract the impasto from RIFF files

Comment: Well, that addon is to import data from another (non free) software....I was hoping I could do it in blender. But I had a dream where I think I figured it out. Maybe if I sculpt and use drivers to deliver the color? I didnt think this through yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer (unfortunately) is "no."

The slightly longer answer is that you might be able to do it with normal maps and textures, but not with a brush-like interface. Dynamic Paint is baked, not live, so you could theoretically make a brush, but you'd have to animate it rather than use it interactively.

Normal maps and displacement maps might create the effect you want, but also not really interactively.

Sculpting is the interaction you want, but there's nothing yet that lets you sculpt and paint at the same time.

Incidentally, you should check out the non-Blender tool [Verve Painter](http://lesterbanks.com/2014/03/verve-painter-fluid-dynamics-paint/) by Timur Baysal. It uses a GPU fluid sim to make digital painting a bit more realistic, and a lot more awesome. And it does some impasto stuff like you're thinking of.

Comment: Sculpt vertex paint in 2.8 let's you sculpt and paint at the same time, at least the functionality was there, but I couldn't find it in 3.1 sculpt branch anymore. https://twitter.com/pablodp606/status/1092163837028171786